# C programming : Read numbers in .txt file containing also character

Tags: c

I would like to read the numbers in the following text file :

```
"lift-rfile"

"Time Step" "report_udf etc.."

("Time Step" "report_udf" "flow-time")

0 0 0

1 4.04136599389973 0.0001

2 -0.05331736530073382 0.0002

3 -0.1326934836267491 0.0003

4 -0.04713889676525063 0.0004
```

Does anyone know how i can do it ? I have tried simply with fscanf starting from line 3 to avoid the characters but it did not work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *How* do you "start from line 3"? Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates what "does not work".

Comment: You'll need to show some code for context.

Answer (score 1):

This would be how I would skip over the first few lines:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (file != NULL)
  {
    int lines = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }

        if (lines > 3) // The number of lines to skip over
        {
            // Begin scanning the numbers, do whatever you need to do with them
            fputc(c, stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file.\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

However, that's not gonna do you much good if the file format is not exactly consistent every time... for example, blank lines. Instead, you may want to check out `isdigit()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void) {
  FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (file != NULL)
  {
    int found_digit = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            found_digit = 1;
        }

        // If we came across a character that is a digit, we can begin our logic.
        if (found_digit)
        {
            // Begin scanning the numbers, do whatever you need to do with them
            fputc(c, stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file.\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0

1 4.04136599389973 0.0001

2 -0.05331736530073382 0.0002

3 -0.1326934836267491 0.0003

4 -0.04713889676525063 0.0004
```

Either way though, it's difficult to know exactly what you want with how little information we've been given.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is exactly as per the format you mentioned, following code can be considered

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char line[100];
    int index;
    float f1, f2;
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (fp = NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Skip three lines by reading three lines and ignoring */
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
    fgets(line, 100, fp);

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d%f%f", &index, &f1, &f2) > 0)
    {
        // do some processing with read values
        printf("%d %f %f\n", index, f1, f2);
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```